# install_github not installing all folders in inst

Tags: r, devtools

I am not sure if I am doing something stupid, but for some reason, all folders in `inst` are not getting installed when I run `install_github('slidify', 'ramnathv', ref = 'dev')`. In particular the folder `inst/scaffold` is not getting installed.

I ran `devtools::install` from the local git repo and everything works fine. I also checked the zipball to make sure that it contained inst\scaffold and it does.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

NOTE. I am cross posting this issue at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/185

Comment: I got a response on `github`. It seems like `scaffold` might be a special directory in `inst`. Renaming it solved the problem. There is still the issue that using `install` from the local `repo` installs `inst/scaffold`, while `install_github` which uses the zipball from github, fails to install it. I am leaving this question open just in case someone has a better explanation for what is happening.

Comment: Can you link to what you mean when you say you posted on github?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify and added a link.